# Python -- Regex match pattern OR end of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
import re
re.findall("(\+?1?[ -.]?\(?\d{3}\)?[ -.]?\d{3}[ -.]?\d{4})(?:[ <$])", "+1.222.222.2222<")
```

The above code works fine if my string ends with a "<" or space. But if it's the end of the string, it doesn't work. How do I get +1.222.222.2222 to return in this condition:

```
import re
re.findall("(\+?1?[ -.]?\(?\d{3}\)?[ -.]?\d{3}[ -.]?\d{4})(?:[ <$])", "+1.222.222.2222")
```

*I removed the "<" and just terminated the string. It returns none in this case. But I'd like it to return the full string -- +1.222.222.2222

POSSIBLE ANSWER:

```
import re
re.findall("(\+?1?[ -.]?\(?\d{3}\)?[ -.]?\d{3}[ -.]?\d{4})(?:[ <]|$)", "+1.222.222.2222")
```

Comment: If you found an answer you should post it in the Answers section, not in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've solved the end-of-string issue, but there are a couple of other potential issues with the pattern in your question:

- the `-` in `[ -.]` either needs to be escaped as `\-` or placed in the first or last position within square brackets, e.g. `[-. ]` or `[ .-]`; if you search for `[]` in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) you'll find the relevant info:

```
Ranges of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them 
by a '-', for example [a-z] will match any lowercase ASCII letter, [0-5][0-9] will match
all the two-digits numbers from 00 to 59, and [0-9A-Fa-f] will match any hexadecimal
digit. If - is escaped (e.g. [a\-z]) or if it’s placed as the first or last character
(e.g. [-a] or [a-]), it will match a literal '-'.
```

- you may want to require that either matching parentheses or none are present around the first 3 of 10 digits using `(?:\(\d{3}\) ?|\d{3}[-. ]?)`

Here's a possible tweak incorporating the above

```py
import re
pat = "^((?:\+1[-. ]?|1[-. ]?)?(?:\(\d{3}\) ?|\d{3}[-. ]?)\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4})(?:[ <]|$)"
print( re.findall(pat, "+1.222.222.2222") )
print( re.findall(pat, "+1(222)222.2222") )
print( re.findall(pat, "+1(222.222.2222") )
```

Output:

```
['+1.222.222.2222']
['+1(222)222.2222']
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
import re
re.findall("(\+?1?[ -.]?\(?\d{3}\)?[ -.]?\d{3}[ -.]?\d{4})(?:| |<|$)", "+1.222.222.2222")
```

- `null` matches any position, `+1.222.222.2222`
- matches space character, `+1.222.222.2222`
- `<` matches less-than sign character, `+1.222.222.2222<`
- `$` end of line, `+1.222.222.2222`

You can also use [regex101](https://regex101.com) for easier debugging.